# Uploadify insecure manner upload

Tags: uploadify

Does anyone knows?

My web server requiring auth, while uploading a file i've got window with auth. Even if I'll put username and pass application is crashed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a known bug in Flash that sends IE cookies regardless of the browser that is hosting the plugin, thus borking your authentication/authorization scheme.

**[Here](http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/03/14/flash-uploaders-vs-asp.net-sessionstate-and-formsauthentication.aspx)** is an asp.net based workaround. It is plainly written and can easily be ported to your environment.